# Getting error in setTargetFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a class named A which extends Fragment in which I am setting the Fragment B (B extends DialogFragment) by

```
     B b = B.newInstance();
     b.setTargetFragment(this,1111);
```

The problem I am facing is that I am getting the squiggly line under **this** which says wrong 1st argument. Found com.xyz.Afragment while expecting android.app.fragment. How to make this work?

Comment: is `this` a subclass of `Fragment` ? If that's the case you have inconsistent fragments import (Make sure that all the fragment imports are from the support library)

Comment: No it is not a subclass of fragment..its the class which extends dialog fragment.

Comment: `DialogFragment` is a Subclass of `Fragment`. Please check the imports and make sure that all are from the support library

Comment: @Blackbelt Thanks. works like a charm. This should be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem I am facing is that I am getting the squiggly line under
>   this which says wrong 1st argument. Found com.xyz.Afragment while
>   expecting android.app.fragment. How to make this work?

if `this` is a subclass of `Fragment` or `DialogFragment`, make sure that all the imports are from the same package. E.g. all from the `support library`, since the native package is deprecated.